# Pywalify - evaluate nested maps

Tags: validation, yaml, schema

I'm using pykwalify to validate a schema.

Given this yaml:

```
variables:
  dev:
    options:
      key: value
  uat:
    key: value
    key2: value
  prd:
    key: value
    key2: value
```

Under variables, any map should be allowed.
Under that second level (dev, uat, prd) - any key should be allowed, EXCEPT options.  "options" should not be allowed here.

I've tried using a regex, but this is only evaluating the top level, and I'm not quite sure how evaluate the level nested under that "dev, uat, prd" level.

```
variables:
  type: map
  matching-rule: all
  mapping:
    regex;([^,]+):
      type: any
    regex;(^(?!.*options:).*$):
      type: any
```

Another potential option would be if I have to explicitly list the values that are allowed, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues in your snippet:

1. The regex to match anything but "options" is wrong.
2. The schema isn't properly structured for the nested mapping.

The following schema should provide what you need:

```yaml
variables:
  type: map
  matching-rule: all
  mapping:
    regex;([^,]+):
      type: map
      mapping:
        regex;(^(?!options$).*):
          type: any
```